# Execution of a piece of code in embedded

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, embedded, atmega328p

Can anyone explain to me step by step
What is the result of executing the code below:

```
DDRB = 0;
unsigned char temp;
temp = (PINB & (1 << 4)) >> 4;
```

Comment: Given that this looks like homework, can you tell us your guess?  Is DDRB mapped to hardware, or is it an ordinary variable.

Comment: @TimWescott 
Hello
No, I found this code on the internet, I tried it in atmela studio but I did not get any results.
There is nothing to explain other than this code.
I am learning the basics of embedded programming.

Comment: `DDRB` is the direction hardware register for port B on AVRs. `PINB` is the digital input register for a port.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Thanks for the question edit as I am new to this site I have not yet learned how to do the question.

Comment: The result is unknown, because it depends on what is the state of port B pin 4.

Answer (score 3):

The code is tagged as ATMega328, so I assume you are coming from an Arduino plaform.

For an AVR, pins are controlled by hardware registers, each of which controls a bank of up to eight pins, known as a "port". For example you will find the pins are labelled as for example: `PA0` (Port A, bit 0), `PB3` (Port B, bit 3) and so on.

Each bank of eight pins are controlled by hardware registers. In the case of the ATMega328p, there are three registers for each port. These are:

- "Direction register" (`DDRx`) - controls whether a pin is an input (0) or an output (1).
- "Output register" (`PORTx`) - sets whether an output drives low (0) or high (1)
- "Input register" (`PINx`) - reads the current state of all pins in the bank, both inputs and outputs.

`DDRB` is the direction register for port B. Setting it equal to zero will set all eight pins on that port to be inputs.

`PINB` is the digital input register for port B. Reading its value will tell you the state of all eight pins on the port.

`(x & (1 << 4)) >> 4;` extracts bit 4 in a value using bit masking followed by bit shifts. In your case `x` is replaced by `PINB`, so you are in effect reading wether Port B, bit 4 (PB4) is high (1) or low (0).